# Music sheet for piano, with two clefs, whats the reason for additional chord symbols?

Tags: piano, chords, sheet-music

In some music sheets, I see two clefs for both hands, but also chord symbols on top, example:

[image]

What is the reason for it? Are this chords just for reference?
Is it enough to just play notes as is on the clefs, or should I use the chords for additional arrangement?
I don't think it's for a second instrument, it's supposed to be arrnaged ofr piano.

Comment: For those who are interested in this song, this is "Summer" by Joe Hisaishi ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7or0noYfMA))

Comment: @AndrewT. And for those who are interested even further, it's the main theme from the movie [Kikujiro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kikujiro).

Comment: And for those who are insterested even further I made an arrangement for guitar. And it includes the chords :-) http://hjg.com.ar/ghibli/musica/kikujiro/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6gXfOR2Lrk

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The chords are for reference, for the sake of other instruments or improvisations.  As a piano player, playing the score is already meeting your quota of notes.  If you want to diverge, the chord symbols may help with that.

Comment: Also, some pianists might want to use the chord names to play a simplified version of the part.

Answer (score 7):

The chord symbols are there mainly for guitarists. They are the names of the chords in each bar, and most guitarists are used to reading the chord symbols when playing along with the piano part.

They are also an opportunity for the piano player to put his own interpretation to the harmonies that the symbols show. Sometimes, I may read exactly what the dots show, others, I'll go by the chord symbols and play different inversions (or extensions) of those chords.

Answer (score 2):

If it's an instructional piece, intended to be played meticulously by a pianist, I don't really know why the chords are there either!

But the written LH part is pretty generic. Plenty of scope to 'do your own thing'. And maybe a guitar or ukelele  might strum along.  Maybe it might be played on a 'home keyboard' where you play the melody with the right hand and hold down a chord shape in the left, letting an 'auto-accompaniment' feature do its stuff.   The chord symbols enable all of this, and more.

Comment: If it's an instructional piece, I still see instructional value in showing the chords so the student knows he's not just playing random notes.